# Strange gap between first HTTP request and others in browser

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser

My English isn't perfect))

I'm interested why I have strange gap between first http request and other requests.

First one screen shows requests delay with laravel php framework.
[image: Http requests screenshots]

Second one screen shows request delay with static page (static page has identical content)
[image: HTTP requests screen 2]

app.css and app.js (see screenshot) are attached in  with standard way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

logo.svg is used with this way:

```
<img src="img/blocks/header/logo.svg">
```

All other files are attached in CSS.

Why I have 75ms delay in first case, and 100ms in second case?
Can I get rid of this pause?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be that it is using a single connection to do all the gets. Setting up connections is slow. Therefore 1st one is slow. This is why it is better to use single connection.

Comment: @richard
1st one is slow cause I'm using laravel php framework.
But if I substitute laravel's generated page with static page (static page with identical content) I'll get 1st request very fast, but other request have the same delay.

[Link to new screenshot](http://s12.postimg.org/7tahktjmz/2015_07_25_11_11_47.png)

Comment: Can you reword your question. After I added my comment, I noticed the arrows on the diagram, they contradict the words, but agree with you last comment. “strange gap between first http request and other requests.” — this suggests that the others are grouped and that the gap is between them and the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.
The reason was a couple of extensions installed in my chrome browser.
Problem disappeared after I had disabled extensions.